# ExtJS Sencha Build getting ext SDK from remote/CDN location

Tags: extjs, cmd, build, sdk

I use ExtJS 5 and build my application using Sencha Cmd.

I have Sencha app generated inside my maven based webapp.

I would like to host the SDK on some CDN and still be able to use Sencha Cmd "sencha app build" etc. Is this possible? I need to trip down the size of my webapp.

**Please guide.**

[image]

Comment: Why would you need that? It doesn't make any sense, in each build you would need to download the SDK. You know that when you run `sencha app build production` all you need to distribute are quite small files in the build/production folder right?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I do understand what you mean.  In my organization we have a limit on project size and I can't keep webapp/extjs anymore inside the webapp directory. I don't want to extract the sencha project and get into CORS issues. Build will be done once in a while and if ext can come from our internal CDN (even if it downloads everytime, we are OK).

Answer (score 0):

Do not upload this folder to source control at all.

Instead, put a readme file to tell fellow developers (who will want to build the dev version of the app) how to install Sencha ExtJS and re-generate this ext folder on their side using this command:

```
cd <path_to_your_app_root>    
sencha app upgrade <path_to_extjs_root_folder>
```

Other project stackholders (Testers, management, ...) should use the production version of the app.

Comment: Thanks. Looks Good. I will try this.